# Evaluation of a summation involving hypergeometric functions

Tags: special-functions, summation

I need help in evaluating the following tricky summation mainly involving a product of two Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function, ${}_1 F_1(a;b;z)$. Is there some identity of ${}_1 F_1(a;b;z)$ that I could use to simplify the product: ${}_1 F_1(1+k;1;b)\times{}_1 F_1(1+n-k;1+n-n';c)$ in the summation?

> $ f(n,n';a,b,c)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{a^{2 k} \, _1F_1(1+k;1;b) \, _1F_1\left(1+n-k;1+n-n';c\right)}{k!
>    \left(n'-k\right)!}$

where, $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants.

Here is the Mathematica code.

```
f[n_, n1_, a_, b_, c_] := Sum[(a^(2 k) Hypergeometric1F1[1 + k, 1, b] Hypergeometric1F1[1 - k + n, 1 + n - n1, c])/(k! (-k + n1)!), {k, 0, n}]
```

Note that in the code, the variable, $n1=n'$.

I'm looking to get a closed-form expression for this summation if it converges. I came across this summation while working on a bigger physics research problem.

Comment: Not sure if this is a MMA question though. Have you tried asking in [the math forum](https://math.stackexchange.com) instead?

Comment: Sometimes plugging in integer values for $k$ (and $n$ and $n'$) will show a pattern as opposed to going for a direct symbolic result.  For example, when `n1=1`, the whole sum simplifies to `Exp[b + c] (n (1 + a^2 (1 + b)) + c)/n`.  So maybe asking how *Mathematica* could search for patterns to simplify your equation (or at least parts of it) might get you more help in this forum.

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, I have also asked the question in the math forum.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for the comment. When I tried evaluating the summation over k for n1=1, Mathematica does not give an answer.

Comment: But if you plug in 1, 2, 3,..., 10 for `n` while leaving `n1=1`, you'll see the pattern and the result I gave in my initial comment.  (If there's a limited range of values for $n$ and $n'$ that you're interested in, that would be helpful to know.  Should I assume you always want $n \geq n'$ ?)

Comment: @JimB Yes, I see your point now. Actually, the overall summations I need to evaluate is the following: $\sum_{n=}^{\infty}\sum_{n'=0}^{\infty} g(n,n') \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{a^{2 k} \, _1F_1(1+k;1;b) \, _1F_1\left(1+n-k;1+n-n';c\right)}{k!
   \left(n'-k\right)!} \sum_{l=0}^{n} \frac{a'^{2 l} \, _1F_1(1+l;1;b') \, _1F_1\left(1+n-l;1+n-n';c'\right)}{l!
   \left(n'-l\right)!}$ where, $g(n,n')$ is a function. The summation over $k$ is posted in the question. There is also a double summation over $n$ and $n'$.

Comment: OK.  But is there the restriction that $n\geq n'$?

Comment: @JimB There is no restriction that $n \geq n'$. A small correction to my earlier comment: The summation range of $n$ is from $0$ to $\infty$. I missed to write $0$.

Comment: You might want to consider a restriction as `f[2,3,a,b,c]` results in `Indeterminate` with the warning `Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity encountered.`

Comment: What @JimB pointed out is, also, why I used $n \geq n^{\prime}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More of an extended comment.

This is following the logic of finding patterns, which I love, and is also suggested by @JimB. Below I give my approach to this kind of problems. By the way, from the two concrete cases I examined it seems that there should be a general formula in terms of `n` and `n1`.

The logic is that we want to re-sum in two variables. We break it down to baby steps as follows.

We assume for concreteness $n \geq n^{\prime}$.

We define the function

```
f[n_, n1_, a_, b_, c_] := 
 Sum[(a^(2 k) Hypergeometric1F1[1 + k, 1, b] Hypergeometric1F1[
      1 - k + n, 1 + n - n1, c])/(k! (-k + n1)!), {k, 0, n}]
```

We generate data from the above like so:

```
Table[f[n, 1, a, b, c], {n, 1, 10}]
```

Then, we find a pattern in the increasing value of `n` by using

```
FindSequenceFunction[{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5}, n]
```

We write down our conjectured formula

```
guess1[n_, a_, b_, c_] := 
 a^2 (1 + b) Exp[b + c] + (1 + c/n) Exp[b + c]
```

and for our peace of minds we verify our analytic guess against higher values of `n` compared to the ones we used in order to guess our answer.

```
Table[f[n, 1, a, b, c] - guess1[n, a, b, c], {n, 1, 21}]
```

The result is

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

as it should.

I am providing another example for clarity. The `n1=2` case. We have our data

```
Table[f[n, 2, a, b, c], {n, 2, 10}]
```

and we make a guess -careful with the shifts in the `FindSequenceFunction` command

```
FindSequenceFunction[{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5}, n] /. n -> n - 1
FindSequenceFunction[{2, 1, 2/3, 1/2, 2/5, 1/3, 2/7, 1/4, 2/9}, n] /. 
 n -> n - 1
FindSequenceFunction[{1/2, 1/6, 1/12, 1/20, 1/30, 1/42, 1/56, 1/72, 
   1/90}, n] /. n -> n - 1
```

We write our conjectured formula

```
guess2[n_, a_, b_, c_] := 
 1/2 a^4 (1 + 2 b + b^2/2) Exp[b + c] + 
  a^2 (1 + b) (1 + c/(n - 1)) Exp[b + c] + (1/
   2) (1 + (2 c)/(n - 1) + c^2/(n (n - 1))) Exp[b + c]
```

and as before we test our result non-trivially by running

```
Table[f[n, 2, a, b, c] - guess2[n, a, b, c], {n, 2, 21}]
```

From the above we get

> `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

as we should.

Once, we have enough analytic formulae in `n` we can try to spot the general pattern; i.e guess a formula in terms of `n1` that produces all the previous analytic results. Once we have that, we verify against a couple of non-trivial results -values for `n` and `n1`- that have not been used in order to do our guesswork.

Now we are done and happy.

Comment: Very good.  Because you've noticed that all combinations of $n>=n'$ have the multiplicative term `Exp[b + c]`, the following would seem to give a strong hint as to the overall pattern:  `Do[Print[TableForm[Table[{n, n1, f[n, n1, a, b, c] /. Exp[b + c] -> 1}, {n, n1, 9 + n1}], TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "n1", "Result"}}]], {n1, 0, 5}]`.

Comment: Precisely. That's how I would go about it, it's just a bit arduous for me to finish off this computation fully right now. But it's pretty obvious that there is indeed a pattern and one should be able to get a closed formula in terms of `n` and `n1`.

Comment: Same here.  Just not enough time in the day.  Also, the definition of $g(x,x')$ is essential as it must drop to zero very quickly.  So in the end it's probably putting a limit on the maximum values of $n$ and $n'$ that will be necessary.  And I learned something new from your answer:  I wrongly assumed that 'FindSequenceFunction` only worked on integers.  Thanks!

Comment: Since you mentioned the `FindSequenceFunction` my experience is that it definitely works better for integers, but for integers we also have the OEIS; see here https://oeis.org/. Bottom line, with enough input and in some cases a well educated ansatz -the academic terminology for a good guess :-) - it should work most of the times.

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 I followed your approach and obtained analytic formulae in terms of $n$ of the form, $h_{n1}(n, a, b, c)$, for $\{n1 = 1, 2, \cdots, 7\}$. It's more arduous to compute analytic formulae for $n1 > 7$. Therefore, as of now, I'm trying to guess a pattern from these 7 expressions to obtain a general formula in terms of $n$ and $n1$. However, I seem to need more and more formulae i.e., corresponding to $n1 > 7$ in order to obtain a closed-form expression in terms of $n$ and $n1$ and I'm kind of stuck here. Is there a better/simpler way to guess the pattern?

Comment: @JayanthJayakumar unfortunately I am not aware of an alternative way to spot the pattern and obtain a closed form formula.

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 By analyzing the patterns, I was finally able to obtain the closed-form expression in terms of $n$ and $n1$ that I was looking for. Here is the expression: $F(n, n1, a, b, c)=\sum_{p=0}^{n1}\sum_{q=0}^{n1}\sum_{r=0}^{n1} \frac{e^{b+c} b^q c^r (n-\text{n1})! a^{2 (\text{n1}-p)}}{(q!)^2 r! (p-r)!
   (n-\text{n1}+r)! (\text{n1}-p-q)!}$ Here's the code: `Sum[(a^(2 (n1 - p)) b^q c^r E^(b + c) (n - n1)!)/((n1 - p - q)! (q!)^2 (p - r)! r! (n - n1 + r)!), {p, 0, n1}, {q, 0, n1}, {r, 0, n1}]`

Comment: Perfect!!! Great job. Good to know that eventually the method worked